# jquery error with multiple checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, post, checkbox

```
<form action="db.php" method="POST" id="addForm" name="addForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="use[]" value="development">Develop<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="use[]" value="sample">Sample<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="use[]" value="mass_production">Mass Prod<br>
</form>
```

Just to clear up first..
1. If I submit, I can get the post values in php using the variable `$_POST['use']` , right ? 
2. Since its multiple checkbox, the values $_POST['use'] is an array, so I need to access it with `$_POST['use'][0]`, `$_POST['use'][1]` , right ?

The real problem now is, when I submit, I received error in console (firebug).
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=use[]]`, and `throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );`

The error prevent my submit. 
I'm using jquery-1.8.2.js. Anything I do wrong ?

UPDATE 
These codes below created the error. But still not understood yet.

```
var jdialog = $('#addnew_dialog');
var jform = jdialog.find('[name=addForm]');
jform.validate({
    errorClass : "err_label",
    wrapper: "li",
    rules: {
        "code": "required",
        "name": "required"
    },
    ignore: "",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if( element.next().hasClass('ui-multiselect') ) {
            error.insertAfter( element.next() );
        } else {
            error.insertAfter( element );
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //use ajax check
        //reset all error state
        $.each($(form).serializeArray(), function() {             
      jform.find("[name="+this.name+"]").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    });

        var data = ajaxCheck("addForm", "ajaxCheckAddShape");
        if(data['result']!="ok"){
            updateTips(data['msg']);
            $.each(data['err_fields'], function(index, value) {
                jform.find("[name="+value+"]").addClass("ui-state-error");
            });
            return false;
        }
        $(form).find("[name=op]").val("add");
        form.submit();
    }
});


function ajaxCheck(formName , action) {
    var jform = $("#"+formName);
    jform.find("[name=op]").val(action);
  var returnData = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db.php",
    async: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    data: jform.serialize(),
    dataType : "json"
  }).responseText;
  return $.parseJSON(returnData);
}
```

Comment: It is generally a good idea, when you have a JavaScript error, to show people the JavaScript code that errors. Just including the jQuery library won't cause that error.

Comment: Post the javascript code involved with that form, that is code about validating the form prior to send or code you use to send the form via ajax..

Comment: If you look at the error in firebug, the stack trace lets you know where is the code.

Comment: FOUND it !!, its `jform.find("[name="+this.name+"]").removeClass("ui-state-error");` .

Comment: Your `jform.find("[name="+this.name+"]")` and similar things can evaluate to `jform.find("[name=use[]]")` so that will throw the error @dystroy was mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a jQuery attribute selector, you need to put quotes if you have characters like `[` or `]`.

For example replace

```
$('[name=use[]]')
```

with

```
$('[name="use[]"]')
```

Comment: I don't access the use variable using my own jquery code. I know to access it must use `$("[name='use[]']")`, but I don't do that. I just want to submit.... thats all ...

Comment: You have some code or there wouldn't be a problem. As Quentin said, just including jQuery can't make your code break on a form submit.